# What can I do about a repeatedly dropping wireless connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, connection

I have a Dell laptop in front of me which is repeatedly dropping its wireless connection. I tried giving it a static IP but that doesn't help; it connects to the router for 10-15 seconds then drops for 30+ seconds. This has been happening for the last few hours.

After a clean install the same problem occurred. I didn't realize that was the problem when I did the clean install so I didn't check it out immediately after but I did notice on the first run of Firefox that one page failed (first run) while the Firefox Google page did not. That was the first thing I tried after the clean installation.

I used the Dell Wireless Manager to run diagnostics. The hardware all passed, except the connection failed at association apart from the few seconds when it connected. When connected it still failed the gateway and Internet ping.

I'm on the same network with my own laptop and it hasn't dropped a single time. Does anyone have any ideas? I plan on doing a completely clean install again and see if it still happens.

**EDIT**: Strange, after a reformat (using ghost so it only took 5mins) I took two minutes to firefox and not have a drop. However after installing it I geot drops repeatedly. Then i reformatted again tried chrome and was not dropped. I then tried firefox and was not dropped. However it did it once or twice later in the day but they were hours apart. I dont understand it but at least it isn't a problem anymore

Comment: Computer or wlan adapter model would help. Also try uninstalling all of the dell ultilities and installing a driver directly from the vendor. Dell drivers are usually pretty good, but I have had a few problems in the past with intel cards and this usually fixes it.

Comment: Do you have any other wireless devices that are causing this issue? Is this a home network or does this occur on any network. You may have a channel conflict issue. If you have a cordless phone that is using the same channel/frequency as your wireless router then this could cause the problem. Or, if there are many people around your home that are using the same channel then it could cause connectivity issues. If this happens on many different wireless networks then update drivers/chipset/firmware.